# A uitable view with 3 groups in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am a developing a ios app with a view controller and a table view in it. i am trying to load list of items in 3 groups but when i compile it it shows correct count but not showing all the items jus repeating items. please help. let me post my code here.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *menuItems;
    NSArray *menuItems2;
    NSArray *dash;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];
    menuItems = @[@"itm1", @"itm2", @"itm3", @"itm4"];
    menuItems2 = @[@"itm1", @"itm2", @"itm3", @"itm4"];
    dash = @[@"itm1", @"itm2"];
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 0) {
        return [menuItems count];
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        return [menuItems2 count];
    }
    if (section == 2) {
        return [dash count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: The code you posted won't compile. There is no `return` at the end of your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't configure your cells. After dequeuing a cell, you have to set its title.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Get the correct array, depending on the current section.
    NSArray *items = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        items = menuItems;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        items = menuItems2;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        items = dash;
    }

    // Get the string from the array and set the cell's title
    NSString *title = items[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Using `if/else` or a `switch` statement would be better.

Comment: True. I just copied OP's implementation of numberOfRowsInSection for a consistent style.

Comment: DrummerB i tried this but nothing happen same result :(

Answer (score 3):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` method needs to be written so the cell is populated with proper data based on the cell's section and row. Right now you don't do anything but use an empty cell.

Comment: @ElGuapo The OP doesn't even use the row.

Comment: Actually... "forIndexPath" does that now

Comment: @ElGuapo But that just gives an empty prototype cell for the index path. The OP's code makes no attempt to populate the cell with any data at all.